# Using superagentjs from window (without require)

Tags: javascript, ajax, superagent

I need to make an asynchronous call from the browser.

I'd like to use [superagentjs](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent), but my current project won't support require().

Is there a way to use superagent from the window object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is accomplished simply by including the superagent.js file on the page as any other javascript, if require is not defined this will simply end up hooking it onto the window at window.superagent.

https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent#browser-build explains that ./superagent.js is the standalone.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays you can generate a superagent.js (usable without Require.js) by running:

```
npm install
make superagent.js
```

within the superagent module folder.